# how to store Authtoken in Shared preference and validate Auth token when call by remote server

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, auth-token

I have an application which is connected to remote server, after registration from android side an Auth token is passed from remote server, where do I need to store that and validate in Android side.

Comment: SharedPreference.

Comment: in shared preference, once stored  how to validate the auth token, how to call in each activity??

Comment: You have to get value from preference in every activity if you want to check in every activity.

Comment: can you help me with demo code,I am a new bie In android

Comment: `where do I need to store that` wherever you want, it's up to you. `and validate in Android side` depends on how exactly you want to validate it.

Comment: while updating profile I want

Comment: don,t know how to make this whole procedure work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting values in SharedPreference:--**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor=prefs.edit();
prefs.putString("key", value);
prefs.commit();
```

**Retrieve data from SharedPreference:--**

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("key", null);
```

Comment: I am getting a auth token from server, can I store like this in shared preference 
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preference name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor=prefs.edit();
prefs.putString("Auth", Auth);
prefs.commit();

Comment: what is your token type  generally it is in string format

Comment: so try it you can save it in SharedPreferences easly

Comment: great please check the answer